# purpose of setting height to 100% for body and html

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

img.one {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

img.two {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
</style>
```

In the css above, when I take out the height property of body and html something seems to happen but I don't understand what.
What is the purpose of setting the height to 100% for body and html?

Comment: Paste your html code to let us see what is actually happening?

Comment: This answer covers it: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the height from `html, body` then `img.two { height: 50%; }` has  no reference height any more. 50% of what should it then be?

Answer (score 2):

Add border to see the differences.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; /* Ex: Change it 100% to %75 */
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

When you done you can remove the line.